# Compiling a Git submodule with my project in Java

Tags: java, git, makefile

I have a GitHub project in Java with the normal file structure:

```
 src/
 src/main.java
 src/com/myproject/MyClass.java
 bin/
```

And I have a `Makefile` for it; but I am adding a Git submodule with its own structure, and within my project it looks as follows:

```
submodule/
submodule/src/
submodule/src/com/project/HelperClass.java
```

My question is what is the normal practice to compile/have multiple projects with different directory structures working together? Should I copy the `src/com/project/` directory into my directory structure?

Comment: can't the submodule deliver a jar ? or compile yourself the subproject as jar and include this jar as library of your project

Comment: I'm looking into it. Be back in 5 : )